# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'scssc' not found in app\code\Magento\SampleScss\Preprocessor\Adapter\Scss\Processor.php:51

Tags: magento2, scss

I have no idea regarding how to make magento use `.scss` instead of `.less` for all styling purpose.

So I went through official documentation available at

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/gulp-sass.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/custom_preprocess.html

and installed module-scss from it's github repo.

https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/module-sample-scss

and put it inside below directory and then run upgrade command.

> `app\code\Magento\SampleScss`

I have created newtheme from scratch for demonstration purpose of compilation of `.scss`.My theme directory structure looks like below.

> `app\design\frontend\Magento\newtheme`

and inside newtheme **newstyle.scss** is inside `web/css` subdirectory thus trying to convert into **newtheme.css** and also add the file to `default_head_blocks.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/newstyle.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

But when I ran deploy command, above error message appears in cli. I am not backend dev so don't know from where issue comes from.

Answer (score 1):

1. It looks like you installed this module manually. In readme they wrote that

   This module is intended to be installed using composer

Maybe you missed some dependency.

2. Another thing according to text  under , do you see generated css file in this location after run deploy command ?

   Run

   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

command and view files in the folder 
pub/static/frontend/Magento//en_US//css. 
CSS file is generated from test SCSS file.

3 it looks like your adapter don't work because class wasn't added. Is this module enabled?
And magento:upgrade

4. What is on line 51 in your Processor.php
5. Maybe better try this is newer:
   https://github.com/splashlab/magento-2-sass-preprocessor